# Creating lists with alternate 0 and 1 as generator in Python

Tags: python, generator

Given a length of list as input:

```
list_len = 5
```

We'd like to create lists that contain 1 and zero:

```
 [1,0,0,0,0]
 [0,1,0,0,0]
 [0,0,1,0,0]
 [0,0,0,1,0]
 [0,0,0,0,1]
```

What's the python way to create generator of such lists?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this with this code:

```
def generate_matrix(size):
    """Generate lists which form an eye matrix"""
    for i in range(size):
        # First, we create a new list with size 0s.
        l = [0] * size
        # At the specified position, we place a 1.
        l[i] = 1
        # We yield this new list.
        yield l
```

It forms a generator which yields the given number of lists, each having the 1 at an advancing position.

Comment: Check this comment. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28166101/creating-lists-with-alternate-0-and-1-as-generator-in-python#comment44702639_28166175

Comment: @howaboutNO I have seen that comment. But my answer answers the question, so that comment does not apply.

Comment: Second part of that comment is apply

Answer (score 1):

If you'd like to create an identity matrix, and do other math calculations, use [`numpy`](http://www.numpy.org/):

```
In [174]: import numpy as np

In [175]: np.eye(list_len)
Out[175]: 
array([[ 1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.]])
```

Comment: Downvoted. Does not answer the question. Secondly, answering like this encourages bad behavior. OP did not even *attempt* to solve it him/herself.

Comment: @GamesBrainiac what if the OP just doesn't know how to describe the question precisely? Voting doesn't help

Comment: Unlikely. Most understood that OP is trying to create an identity matrix, I'm sure the OP him/herself knows that as well. A simple google search, will reveal how to do this with the `eye` function. But that is not my main concern, my main concern is that you jumped to answer the question, where the OP has not even shown *any* effort to solve it. This kind of knee-jerk responses will only extend StackOverflow's image of a place where you can get people to code for you for free. I for one, expect *some* effort, even if it just writing a blank function.

Answer (score 1):

As a list comprehension:

```
size = 5
mIter = xrange(size)
matrixList = [[1 if i==x else 0 for i in mIter] for x in mIter]
print matrixList
```

Answer (score 1):

The Pythonic way to create such lists would be by using lists comprehensions :

```
[ [ 1 if i == j else 0 for j in range(5)] for i in range(5)]
```

BTW, a *generator* is a special object in Python. Here is how to build a generator for the same lists :

```
def gen():
    for i in range(5):
        yield [ 1 if i == j else 0 for j in range(5)]
```

Usage of the above generator :

```
for l in gen():
    print(l)
```